# Change date input value format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am implementing a fake form in an HTML page. I have several inputs that I need to transform in order to be sent using a POST request.

One of the problems I am facing is related with the date format.
I have a `<input type="date">`which returns its value like this: `2017-12-28`, and I need to change its format and turn it into this: `28/12/2017`. I can only use jQuery.

Is there a specific function to do this? Or do I have to parse it? I am pretty lost: (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the solution without using any plugin.

```js
var defaultDate = "2017-12-28";
var splitedValues = defaultDate.split("-");
var newDateFormat = splitedValues[2]+"/"+splitedValues[1]+"/"+splitedValues[0];
console.log(newDateFormat);
alert(newDateFormat);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var date = new Date('2017-12-28');
alert(date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' +  date.getFullYear());
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

```js
var parts = '2017-12-28'.split('-'); 
var dmyDate = parts[2] + '/' + parts[1] + '/' + parts[0];
console.log(dmyDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var userBirthDate = '2017-12-01';
userBirthDate = userBirthDate.split("-").reverse().join("/");
console.log(userBirthDate);
```

Comment: While this code might answer the question, it is usually considered good practice to add an explanation of what your code does. This allows for developers who are not knowledgeable in this area to understand what is going on in the code and helps them to learn how to solve the problem by them selves in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( function() {
 $( "#date" ).datepicker();
    //set the date format here
    $( "#date" ).datepicker("option" , "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy");
 } );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<input type="text" id="date">
```

Answer (score 0):

A date input's value is always formatted `yyyy-mm-dd`, although the displayed format may vary based on the user's locale. Parsing it isn't hard though.

```
var myDate = $("#myinput").val().split("-").reverse().join("/")
```

## How does that work?

We get the value from our date input, and split it into parts separated by dashes `"-"`. So now we have an array like `["2017", "12", "28"]`.
Then, we reverse it, so it's in the order we want: `["28", "12", "2017"]`.
Then, we join the elements using slashes, giving us `"28/12/2017"`

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this. Something like this

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker-13" ).datetimepicker({
        //format : 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm'
        viewMode: 'days',
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
    }, "date");
    var dateNow = new Date();
    var date= moment(dateNow).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
    $('#datepicker-13').attr("value", date);

});
```